# Conditionally link radio options to other questions?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, forms, formbuilder, fields

I've created a **public profile** with some **custom fields**. This is the page in question: https://crm.ingenium.org.mx/solicitud-de-admision/. I would like to **link the radio button options** of the last question and have **other questions appear depending on the selection** (Same as in a Microsoft Form or Google Form) This is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are needing to stick with profiles which are now the "legacy / old-school" way to do forms, then you will need to utilize [profile conditionals](https://civicrm.org/extensions/profile-conditionals). At some point profiles will be set aside and replaced entirely with [Form Builder](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/creating-new-forms/).

But it doesn't look like your form requires any functionality exclusive to profiles, so I would recommend a conversion to Form Builder which [provides conditionals as of Civi 5.69](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24699).

Note: Payments is one of the features not available in Form Builder which is still an [MIH in progress](https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen/formbuilder-support-contributions).